# Building gRPC C++ from source

Tags: c++, grpc, bazel

I am trying to build `gRPC c++` from source from [Build gRPC C++](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/BUILDING.md)
I have already installed bazel. 
Though when I tried to build I am seeing following error.

```
$ bazel build :all
Starting local Bazel server and connecting to it...
ERROR: /home/bigz/.cache/bazel/_bazel_bigz/a68d37101a3d172c639dd67a1941f719/external/io_bazel_rules_python/python/pip.bzl:39:25: Traceback (most recent 
call last):
        File "/home/bigz/.cache/bazel/_bazel_bigz/a68d37101a3d172c639dd67a1941f719/external/io_bazel_rules_python/python/pip.bzl", line 37
                repository_rule(<2 more arguments>)
        File "/home/bigz/.cache/bazel/_bazel_bigz/a68d37101a3d172c639dd67a1941f719/external/io_bazel_rules_python/python/pip.bzl", line 39, in repositor
y_rule
                attr.label(allow_files = True, <2 more arguments>)
'single_file' is no longer supported. use allow_single_file instead. You can use --incompatible_disable_deprecated_attr_params=false to temporarily disable th
is check.
ERROR: error loading package '': Extension file 'python/pip.bzl' has errors
ERROR: error loading package '': Extension file 'python/pip.bzl' has errors
INFO: Elapsed time: 7.505s
INFO: 0 processes.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (0 packages loaded)
```

Could someone point what I am missing here.

When I tried to run `bazel info`, I am getting following error.

```
$ bazel info --incompatible_disable_deprecated_attr_params=false
ERROR: /home/bigz/.cache/bazel/_bazel_bigz/a68d37101a3d172c639dd67a1941f719/external/org_pubref_rules_protobuf/protobuf/internal/proto_compile.bzl:771:21: name 'FileType' is not defined
ERROR: error loading package '': in /home/bigz/.cache/bazel/_bazel_bigz/a68d37101a3d172c639dd67a1941f719/external/org_pubref_rules_protobuf/python/rules.bzl: in /home/bigz/.cache/bazel/_bazel_bigz/a68d37101a3d172c639dd67a1941f719/external/org_pubref_rules_protobuf/cpp/rules.bzl: in /home/bigz/.cache/bazel/_bazel_bigz/a68d37101a3d172c639dd67a1941f719/external/org_pubref_rules_protobuf/protobuf/rules.bzl: Extension 'protobuf/internal/proto_compile.bzl' has errors
```

Though `bazel --version` shows as `bazel 2.0.0`.

```
$ bazel --version
bazel 2.0.0
```

The latest commit of gRPC is `9dfbd34f5c0b20bd77658c73c59b9a3e4e8f4e14`

```
$ git log -1
commit 9dfbd34f5c0b20bd77658c73c59b9a3e4e8f4e14 (HEAD, tag: v1.20.0)
Merge: 1b488f8361 ae72bf76b3
Author: Lidi Zheng <scallopsky@gmail.com>
Date:   Mon Apr 15 15:38:24 2019 -0700

    Merge pull request #18760 from lidizheng/v1.20.x

    Bump version to v1.20.0
```

Comment: What version of bazel are you using here? `bazel info` will give some good info.
The commit sha of grpc would be helpful here too.

Comment: I am using `bazel 2.0.0`. The commit sha of grpc is `9dfbd34f5c0b20bd77658c73c59b9a3e4e8f4e14`. I could not run `bazel info` as well. I updated my post with the error I faced while running bazel info.

Comment: Could you share how I can build grpc from a version + sha like `v1.12.1-8480-g2de2e8dd89`. I couldn't find instructions to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The commit of grpc you are trying to build is not compatible with the version of bazel you have installed (2.0.0).

The commit `9dfbd34f5c0b20bd77658c73c59b9a3e4e8f4e14` is quite old (15 April 19), where the HEAD of that repo (at the time of writing this) is at `eba60d8dbe4099c34b8097b2c89998d4484740ac`, which now in [BUILDING.md](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/BUILDING.md) shows you need at least version 1.0.0 (there is a bazel wrapper at `tools/bazel` that will intercept and use 1.0.0 anyway)

For your specific commit however, trying different versions, I was able to build `:all` label with bazel version [0.20.0](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/releases/tag/0.20.0)

I'd recommend trying [bazelisk](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazelisk). You can add it to your PATH, add a `.bazelversion` file to the repository and bazelisk will take care of downloading the required bazel version.

Comment: When I pointed my HEAD to `eba60d8dbe4099c34b8097b2c89998d4484740ac`, I am able to build. Thank you.

I will try `bazelisk` some time later.